# Correct way to format Haskell functions considering scope?

Tags: haskell, scope

I'm new to Haskell. I've put together a basic Caesar Cipher, it works, but it's very messy and difficult to read.

```
caesarCipher :: Int -> String -> String
caesarCipher n xs = [shift n x | x <- xs] 
shift n c  = num2let ((let2num c + n) `mod` 26)
alphabet = ['a'..'z']
let2num c = head[ b | (a,b) <- zip alphabet [0..length alphabet], a==c]
num2let = (!!) alphabet
```

What is the "correct" way in Haskell to format functions that consist of multiple variables and expressions, and should I be considering the **scope** of the variables? And other than efficiency based suggestions have I made any other "major" mistakes?

This is my attempt:

```
caesarCipher n xs = let
    shift n c  = num2let ((let2num c + n) `mod` 26) where
        alphabet = ['a'..'z']
        let2num c = head[ b | (a,b) <- zip alphabet [0..length alphabet], a==c]
        num2let = (!!) alphabet
    in [shift n x | x <- xs]
```

Comment: I don't think your code is too bad, I only find it difficult to read because you've got no blank lines between each definition. Also, you should really put a type signature above each definition, as you already have with `caesarCipher`.

Comment: @RobinZigmond In my first example each function/variable that caesarCipher utilises are also available to the entire file, is this correct?

Comment: @Giles: not each variable, as in the `n` of `caesarCipher` is locally scoped (well it would be "odd" that it is globally scoped). But reusing functions is quite popular in most programming languages. So there is no problem to make `let2num` a function that can be reused for other (cryptographic) functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would first of all rewrite some functions. For example. `zip alphabet [0 .. length alphabet]` can be replaced with `zip alphabet [0..]`, since the `zip` will stop from the moment one of the lists is exhausted. Making use of `(!!)` and `head` is often not good practice, since these functions are non-total: if the index is too large, or the list is empty, `(!!)` and `head` will error respectively.

We can define helper functions, for example for `num2let`:

```
import Data.Char(chr, ord)

num2let :: Int -> Char
num2let n = chr (n + ord 'a')
```

here `num2let` will map `0` to `'a'`, `1` to `'b'`, etc.

`let2num` can be done in a similar manner:

```
import Data.Char(ord)

let2num :: Char -> Int
let2num c = ord c - ord 'a'
```

So now we can define `caesarCipher` as:

```
caesarCipher :: Int -> String -> String
caesarCipher n = map (num2let . (`mod 26`) . (n+) . let2num)
```

So that would look in full as:

```
import Data.Char(chr, ord)

num2let :: Int -> Char
num2let n = chr (n + ord 'a')

let2num :: Char -> Int
let2num c = ord c - ord 'a'

caesarCipher :: Int -> String -> String
caesarCipher n = map (num2let . (`mod` 26) . (n+) . let2num)
```

The nice thing is that you can here reuse the `let2num` and `num2let` for other functions.

Normally top-level functions are separated with a blank line, and are given a signature. This is not *necessary*, but makes it usually more convenient to read.